# Retain Aspect Ratio of a Window when Resized

Tags: windows, window, aspect-ratio

I'd like to, for example, be able to hold Shift in order to keep the aspect ratio of a window the same when I'm resizing it by clicking and dragging the arrows which appear on the side of the window - similar to how you can hold Shift to maintain a window's aspect ratio in OSX or an image's ratio in Paint.NET. Possible on Microsoft Windows?